# why expression [code] is accepted by python? what is origin of that?

Tags: python

I wrote this expression

```
[0 for j in range(4)]
```

and python accepted it as definition of list, but when i wrote this expression:

```
0 for j in range(4)
```

it raises an error.

what is mechanism of that and from which language does it origin? is it from functional programming ie. LISP? What is equivalent in Java or C?

EDIT: the difference from answered question is that there is not left part of equitation, just right part

```
[code]
```

Also I was interested in origin of list comprehension and equivalents in other programming languages.

Comment: The idea is taken from Haskell.

Comment: Note that you can create a *generator expression* with parentheses: `(0 for j in range(4))`.

Comment: And the PEP that defined the syntax: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I'm not sure that the Python developers took it from Haskell directly. The concept and name existed in NPL already, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions Though it's hard to say Greg Ewing was thinking of Haskell when he added the related patches.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is result of that expression, i get generator and can't print it.

Comment: A generator *is* the result of that expression! If you want to see what it contains, you need to *consume it* by iterating over it.

Comment: does it have any purpose?

Answer (score 2):

`[0 for j in range(4)]` is a [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).  This is perfectly valid Python syntax.

The other expression isn't an expression at all.